# How to set up multiple repositories in R and use global as a fallback?

Tags: r, cran

I attempted to leave a comment on this post ["What is the behavior of install packages in case multiple repos are specified"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58341427/what-is-the-behavior-of-install-packages-in-case-multiple-repos-are-specified) but unfortunately don't have enough reputation yet so am starting a new, very similar question.

Essentially like the OP in that post, I am looking to set up a local repository of specific versions of widely used packages in my org. We have a lot of people using a lot of different scripts, however people usually come to me for R help and it can be difficult to debug when everyone is on different versions of the packages. I thought the easiest way would be to create a local repo for the team where all packages are installed from if possible that I maintain and test. Then if a package isn't in this repo, it's not a widely used one and defaults to installing directly from global CRAN. This will allow me to test our scripts for version issues before updating everyone off of a version that works, whilst still allowing the team to use obscure packages if necessary.

Is there a way to set up this fallback repo, or is there perhaps a better way people recommend that I'm not aware of for team-wide version control? I know that, for example, in pip/python you can have a `requirements.txt` file with all required packages and versions, so you just run `pip install requirements.txt` and it'll install exactly those versions of the packages listed. Does something like this exist for R perhaps? I know I could build a package as an option for this but that is a decent amount of extra development time, so would prefer to find a different way around first before going into this development time.

Hopefully that all makes sense, thanks for your answers in advance!